# IOS 8 can't dismiss keyboard from UITextField

Tags: ios, ios8, uitextfield, uialertview

I believe my issue is similar to: [iOS 8 Keyboard Dismissed delay after modal view controller is dismissed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306381/ios-8-keyboard-dismissed-delay-after-modal-view-controller-is-dismissed/27610989#27610989) but I'm unclear from the other thread how to work around it in my application.

In Xcode5/IOS7, I show a UIAlertView with 2 UITextFields. The user can simply press OK and move on, or they can enter a password / confirm password in the textfields. In IOS7, I hid the keyboard when I showed the alertview, and the keyboard would automatically re-appear if/when the user tapped into the text field:

```
UIAlertView *startTurnAlert;
UITextField *textField0, *textField1;
startTurnAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Player %d, Begin Turn %d",playerNumber, turnNumber]
                      message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, report for duty!", playerNames[playerNumber] ]
                      delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Exit Game"
                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK",
                                        nil
                      ];
startTurnAlert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;

textField0 = [startTurnAlert textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField0.secureTextEntry = YES;
textField0.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField0.placeholder = @"Enter a passcode (optional)";

textField1 = [startTurnAlert textFieldAtIndex:1];
textField1.placeholder = @"Re-enter passcode";
textField0.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;

[startTurnAlert show];
[textField0 endEditing:YES];
[textField1 endEditing:YES];
```

after updating to Xcode 6 and building for IOS8, with no code changes, the keyboard never hides. I tried adding resignFirstResponder as such, with no luck:

```
[startTurnAlert show];
[textField0 resignFirstResponder];
[textField0 endEditing:YES];
[textField1 resignFirstResponder];
[textField1 endEditing:YES];
```

So, in IOS8, how can I hide the keyboard for a UItextField embedded in a UIAlertview *until* the user actually indicates an intent to enter text by tapping on the text field?

Thanks!

Comment: UIAlertView has been deprecated, I doubt that is the cause, but it could be.  If you only want to support iOS 8+, you may want to use UIAlertController.  It has textfield support in the API.

Comment: After looking at the code again, you might want to try and not call endEditing right after show and see what happens. Also try dismissing before you call show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, trying to hide the keyboard which was in a *modal* popup window.  `resignFirstResponder` would just do nothing.

The solution... was to *disable* all `UITextFields` controls in the dialog (so iOS couldn't latch onto any controls which required the keyboard), and then re-enable the relevant ones a fraction of a second later.

It's annoying, but it works...

(Sigh.)

Comment: Just to clarify: you disabled, hid the keyboard, then re-enabled? Or did you disable, re-enable, then hide?

Comment: No, I disabled the controls... at which point the onscreen keyboard *automatically* slid away, and then, a fraction of a second later, I re-enabled the controls that I wanted the user to be able to enter text in.

Comment: Interesting. It works great on an ipadAir, as long as I delay at least 750ms after showing the alertView before re-enabling the text fields. If I re-enable any sooner, the keyboard comes back upon re-enabling. That's certainly an acceptable delay. However, on an older 32-bit iPad2, the delay has to be at least 5.0 seconds... sometimes as much as 7.0 seconds, or else the keyboard pops back up. I'm gonna go with the 750ms, and just accept that slower devices won't benefit.

Comment: Ridiculous, hey ?!   Just remember that Apple's official line on this is that it *isn't possible* to turn off the onscreen keyboard on modal dialogs.  So this little quirk might go away with iOS 9.   But it works for now  (and is better than nothing...)

Comment: Oh... and it took me *almost a day* of trying all kinds of methods to turn off the keyboard until I finally stumbled on this idea !  So, a lot of anger, swearing and hair-pulling went into those two paragraphs in my answer !!!   Glad it worked for you.

Comment: I spent days on this myself and there were more than a few choice words here, too. Never thought of disabling the box, though. BTW, do you have a ref to Apple's official position? They closed my bug as no repro; they didn't say it was not supported.

Comment: No, there's a link to the Apple position on one of these StackOverflow pages, where someone included the link to confirm that, nope, this isn't possible...  but I can't remember which (of the many) articles included the link...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if anyone has the same issue with iOS9 like me, but I managed to get it working by doing this way:

1. Try to focus on one of the textfield

   ```
   [self.someTextfield becomeFirstResponder];
   ```
2. Then delay it, then remove the focus

   ```
   double delayInSeconds = 0.5; // set the time
   dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
   dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){  
       [self.someTextfield resignFirstResponder];  
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Since it worked in iOS 7 and you've spent awhile on this, I would just implement something like the second block of code in the question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074475/uialertview-vs-uialertcontroller-no-keyboard-in-ios-8)
Starting at if [uialertcontroller class]

Comment: I'm still seeing the same behavior.

Comment: Try calling it on the VC instead of the alertView

Comment: did you implement textFieldShouldEndEditing?

Comment: yeah, but still no luck. Should I resignFirstResponder in the textFieldShouldEndEditing? or do I just return YES?

Comment: after a few days of on and off experimenting, I'm giving up. Thanks anyway.