# How to get an UIAlertView subview UITextField value in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

guys I just created an `alertview`, that have 3 fields in the subview as follows:

```
//----adding an alertview----
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Vehicle Information" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add", nil];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 300);
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

UITextField* text1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 10,self.view.frame.size.width-125, 30)];
text1.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
UITextField* text2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 45, self.view.frame.size.width-125, 30)];
text2.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
UITextField* text3 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 80, self.view.frame.size.width-125, 30)];
text3.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
text1.layer.borderColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
text1.layer.borderWidth=1;
text2.layer.borderColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
text2.layer.borderWidth=1;
text3.layer.borderColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
text3.layer.borderWidth=1;
text1.placeholder=@"Year";
text2.placeholder=@"Make";
text3.placeholder=@"Model";
[view addSubview:text1];
[view addSubview:text2];
[view addSubview:text3];
[alertView setValue:view forKey:@"accessoryView"];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
alertView.tag = 1;
[alertView show];
```

[image]

now i want to get the textfield value, clicking save button does call the following class but i am not getting the value.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
NSLog(@"AlertView is Active");
if (alertView.tag == 1 && buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {
    NSLog(@"alert view working");
    NSString *Year = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    NSLog(@"%@",Year);
}
```

}

and i am getting an empty value as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[alertView textFieldAtIndex:] only work when you set alertView.alertViewStyle .

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIAlertViewStyle) {
    UIAlertViewStyleDefault = 0,
    UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput,
    UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput,
    UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput
};
```

Comment: sorry i didnt get ur answer, do u have an alternative way where i could access text1 text2 text3?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the textfield to a UIView and setting it as the accessoryView. To use the **textFieldAtIndex** method you have to use a different **UIAlertViewStyle** as mentioned in this [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/textFieldAtIndex:). Also the document clearly states that "the view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified". And UIAlerView is deprecated in iOS 8 so use UIAlertController class instead.

Since you are setting the "accessoryView" to a UIView. You can access that view using

```
  UIView *myView = [alertView valueForKey:@"accessoryView"];
```

and find the text field using a tag value using the method

```
 UITextField * textFeld = [myView viewWithTag:100];
```

Comment: thanks, u were right, i am using UIAlertController, works really good now, i followed the following question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074475/uialertview-vs-uialertcontroller-no-keyboard-in-ios-8

Comment: i searched a lot to get an alert view with more then 2 text fields, the above stackoverflow have its solution